# Angular 1.4.8 Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am unable to find/pinpoint the root cause of the error. 
In my javascript file I keep getting a green squiggly under the the word `angular`. I don't understand why.  (Im using Visual Studio Code)

HTML

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
        <head>
            <title>Hello</title>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\john\Desktop\test.js"/>

        </head>
        <body >
            <div>
                <label>Name:</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter name here">

                <h1> Hello, {{yourName}}</h1>

                <div ng-controller="HelloController">
                    <h2>Say hello to {{helloTo.title}} </h2>
                    </div>


         </body>
    </html>
```

Javascript

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);

app.controller("HelloController", function($scope){
    $scope.helloto={};
    $scope.helloto.title="AngularJS";

});

})();
```

ERROR

```
 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]  http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=myapp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.8%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dmyapp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A24%3A186%0A%20%20%20%20at%20b%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A23%3A251)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A23%3A494%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A117%0A%20%20%20%20at%20n%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A333)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A37%3A488)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20eb%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A41%3A249)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A463
```

Comment: Include the JS for `ngRoute`

Comment: There is a separate JS for ngRoute ?

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the javascript file for ng-route.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.2/angular-route.min.js

That is the cdn for it. Load it in and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware. Angular Route has it's own JS

Comment: Thats okay. For future reference, this is a website for the CDNs for a lot of angularjs modules. https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular.js/  That should make things a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

You have to refer the script for ng-route

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-route.js">
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you didn't add the `ng-route.js` file since your requiring it in `angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);`

try to add this `js` right after the `angular.js` in `html` file

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-route.js

and check `C:\Users\john\Desktop\test.js` is loading correctly